# I am unable to start webstorm from the fedora command line, after following the instructions on the website

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, path, webstorm

[On start up, the JetBrains Toolbox opens up fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33BzN.png)

[The 'Generate shell scripts' is active and the shell scripts location is as JetBrains instructions states ('/usr/local/bin')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4cPv.png) and the Shell script name is 'webstorm'.

However, after I type webstorm into the terminal. It returns: `bash: webstorm: command not found...`

[Then, if I return to the JetBrains toolbox it is just a blank screen. Closing and re-opening the toolbox does nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX474.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have write permission to `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Thank you @rickhg12hs this was the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation of `JetBrains`, `WebStorm`, or any application/library requires write permission to its installation location.

In this case, write permission to `/usr/local/bin` is required.